# When should I use matrix.astype and when matrix.view?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a matrix of int32 integers (50k x 50k or so) which I need to convert to float32. I can do that with

```
# Preparation for the example
import numpy as np
n = 50_000
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, n), dtype='int32')

# Way 1:
matrix = matrix.astype(np.float32, copy=False)

# Way 2:
matrix = matrix.view(np.float32)
```

When should  I use which one? Is there a speed-disadvantage in later use of a view compared to a "real" numpy array?

### What I tried

#### Execution time analysis (creation, not later access)

```
import numpy as np
import timeit


def create_boxplot(duration_list, showfliers=False):
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import operator

    plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 4), dpi=300, facecolor="w", edgecolor="k")
    sns.set(style="whitegrid")
    sorted_keys, sorted_vals = zip(
        *sorted(duration_list.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    )
    flierprops = dict(markerfacecolor="0.75", markersize=1, linestyle="none")
    ax = sns.boxplot(
        data=sorted_vals,
        width=0.3,
        orient="h",
        flierprops=flierprops,
        showfliers=showfliers,
    )
    ax.set(xlabel="Time in ms", ylabel="")
    plt.yticks(plt.yticks()[0], sorted_keys)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("output.png")


n = 5_000
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, n), dtype='int32')
print(matrix.dtype)

matrix = matrix.view(np.float32)
print(matrix.dtype)

timeit_d = {}
timeit_d["repeat"] = 500
timeit_d["number"] = 3
timeit_d["setup"] = "import numpy as np; n=5_000; matrix = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n, n), dtype='int32')"

duration_list = {}

# Way 1
durations = timeit.repeat(
    "matrix2 = matrix.view(np.float32)",
    setup=timeit_d["setup"],
    repeat=timeit_d["repeat"],
    number=timeit_d["number"],
)
duration_list["view"] = durations
print("Done views")

# Way 2
durations = timeit.repeat(
    "matrix2 = matrix.astype(np.float32)",
    setup=timeit_d["setup"],
    repeat=timeit_d["repeat"],
    number=timeit_d["number"],
)
duration_list["astype"] = durations
print("Done astype")

# Visualize
create_boxplot(duration_list)
```

[image]

Clearly views are way faster than astype.

#### Memory analysis

```
$ valgrind --tool=massif python3 foobar.py
$ massif-visualizer massif.out.view
```

Clearly shows that the `view` option uses WAY less memory.

Comment: `Way 1` and `Way 2` return different arrays. `astype()` transforms the array data to a different type, whereas `view()` just interprets the memory as a data type without actually changing anything. My guess is you want to stick to `Way 1`.

Comment: Where does this actually make a difference? Is accessing the data slower? Is Matrix multiplication slower for the interpreted one? Are results actually different?

Comment: Make your life easy and simply look at the two result arrays. "look" as in let the interpreter print them out for you

Comment: @PaulPanzer That was only a problem in my example. The question still remains.

Comment: Shouldn't you be reinitializing matrix as `matrix = np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, n), dtype='int32')` inbetween the two methods? Also, because you are assigning to matrix inside your timeit, does that not make the first iteration where matrix is full of ints different from the subsequent ones where it's full of floats? Maybe `matrix 2 = matrix.view...` would make more sense?

Comment: @Dan The first one is an "either way 1, or way 2". The example code was adjusted.